# how to verify header exist?

Tags: node.js, authentication, token, jwt

Using Node.js, I am able to create a user an assign a token via jwt.sign().  This seems to be working.  The error is when I try to validate that the user is logged in.  I try to verify that the header exist but req.headers.authorization gives me undefined.

//login, this seems to work fine.

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    console.log('logging in a Auth_user')
    console.log(req.body)

      models.Auth_user.findOne({
    where: {email: req.body.email}
  }).then(function(user) {
        // console.log(user)
        console.log(user.email)
        console.log(user.first_name)
        console.log(user.password)

        if (user == null){
            console.log('no user found with email')
            // res.redirect('/users/sign-in')
        }

        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result) {

        if (result == true){
            console.log('password is valid')
            var token = jwt.sign({ username: user.email }, 'passwordgoeshere', { expiresIn: 600 });

            return res.send()

            res.status(200).json({success: true, token: token});
            res.redirect('/holders')

        }
        else{
            console.log('password incorrect')
                    res.redirect('/home')
                }
    });
  })

};
```

//authenticate, this is where I cannot verify header

```
module.exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
console.log('authenticating')
console.log(req.headers.authorization)

  var headerExists = req.headers.authorization;

  if (headerExists) {
    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]; //--> Authorization Bearer xxx
    jwt.verify(token, 'passwordgoeshere', function(error, decoded) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401).json('Unauthorized');
      } else {
        req.user = decoded.username;
        var authenticated = true;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).json('No token provided');
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show the client side code in which you send the `Authorization` header to the server? FWIW, that's something that you have to do in code, it's not something that a browser will do automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Use either `req.headers['authorization']` or `req.header('authorization')`

You must also check that `authorization` header is exposed in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` of your Nodejs authentication server in order your client is able to send it.

**Sample code**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: `req.headers['authorization']` is the same as `req.headers.authorization`.

Comment: Yep. You can also use `req.header('authorization')`

Comment: But that's just the problem: `req.headers.authorization` doesn't exist.

Comment: Then it must not be exposed by authentication server

Comment: My guess is that the client isn't _sending_ it. Also, `Authorization` isn't a response header but a request header, so `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` doesn't apply.

Comment: You're maybe right. But we miss some information. Does it nodejs act as a client of his authentication server or a proxy for its client webapp ?

Comment: Node.js is the server that the client is talking to, so Node _is_ the authentication server in that respect.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I read his code too quickly. Another possibility is that `authorization` header is not allowed in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` list

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");

var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['Authorization'] || req.headers['authorization'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], process.env.SECRET_KEY);`
console this and you will get your token